# Yet another JSON jQuery error

Tags: jquery, json

My Server returns:

```
{"content":"<div>\n <form style=\"width: auto\" id=\"pictureUploadForm\" method=\"POST\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" action=\"https://localhost/simmapp/action/admin.CMSAction\">\n     <label for=\"fileUpload\">Choose File : </label><br/>\n     <input type=\"file\" name=\"fileUpload\" /><br/>\n      <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"eventSubmit_uploadFile\" value=\"T\"/>\n      <span class=\"tip\">Warning this will refresh page, potentially losing unsaved work.<br/>\n </form>\n   <button class=\"button\" onclick=\"CMSManager.submitUpload()\">Upload File</button>\n</div>"}
```

According to JSONLint that's valid, and another JSON validator (http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) says the same.

So why does jQuery.getJSON fail?

I'm about ready to get rid of jquery and go back to using jxs.js as it worked fine for years. jQuery is a PITA.

```
jx.load(link.getURL(), function(data){
  PopUp.add({
   content:data.content,title:"Upload File",
   closeable:true})
}, "json","GET");
```

Works

```
$.getJSON(link.getURL(), function (data) {
  PopUp.add({content:data.content,title:"Upload File",closeable:true})
});
```

Doesn't. I realize jx doesn't do any JSON parsing(it just uses eval). I've been trying to migrate over to jQuery, but it's been painful.

The jQuery section fails silently, which is generally assumed to be a parse error. But I can't see the problem.

Comment: Let's see how you are using it, can we see some code ?

Comment: Agreed. What you've provided doesn't clearly explain what is happening and why its not working for you.

Comment: Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/2DUQK/.  Granted, I had to modify it slightly to make it play by jsfiddle's rules.  I don't know if any of those modifications accidentally "fixed" your issue.

Comment: So ok, I should have realized tabs need to be escaped. But what is boggling to me, is that I can cut and paste the first response into JSONLint and it passes, whereas it fails on JSON.parse from a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{"content":"<div><form style=\"width: auto\" id=\"pictureUploadForm\" method=\"POST\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" action=\"http://localhost/simmapp/action/admin.CMSAction\"><label for=\"fileUpload\">Choose File : </label><br/><input type=\"file\" name=\"fileUpload\" /><br/><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"eventSubmit_uploadFile\" value=\"T\"/><span class=\"tip\">Warning this will refresh page, potentially losing unsaved work.<br/></form><button class=\"button\" onclick=\"CMSManager.submitUpload()\">Upload File</button></div>"}
```

Works, can you spot the difference?    \t  Tabs, apparently in addition to newlines, parseJSON doesn't like tabs either.

Comment: Oddly JSONLint throws an error when I try to put in a tab manually, but it passes the first string even though JSON.parse in Firefox/Chrome doesn't.